# Геопозиционирование на PHP

Tags: php

Здравствуйте.
Мне бы хотелось узнать, возможно ли без подключения сторонних библиотек и фреймворков, на PHP определить точные координаты пользователя, который зашел на сайт?

Comment: Подключите к пользователю железяку с GPS, напишите протокол работы с ней (свой, на PHP, без сторонних библиотек) - и получите искомое.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Sypex Geo — быстрое определение города по IP](http://habrahabr.ru/post/146597/)

По мне, так самое лучше на данный момент решение, а главное, довольно шустрое, ибо гео-данные хранятся в бинарном виде.

Answer (score 2):

- http://freegeoip.net/
- http://www.telize.com/

Ничего не могу сказать по поводу двух сервисов, так как их не использовал, но они бесплатны.

Answer (score 2):

На подобный [вопрос я отвечал 2012 году](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/178999/%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B0-php).

#### Sypex Geo

Доступны БД стран, регионов и городов в бинарном виде. Данный проект по-прежнему активно развивается, базы поддерживаются в актуальном виде. Имеется библиотека на PHP (официальная), Python и Ruby. С тех пор в рамках проекта появились платные сервисы ([удалённый REST API](http://sypexgeo.net/ru/api/)), но всё что было бесплатным, [остаётся таковым и по сей день](http://sypexgeo.net/ru/download/).

- [Статья на хабре за 2012 год](http://habrahabr.ru/post/146597/)
- [Другие публикации на хабре автора](http://habrahabr.ru/search/?q=Sypex+Geo)
- [Оф. сайт](http://sypexgeo.net/ru/)

#### TabGeo

На данный инструмент наткнулся в этом году. Аналогично, как и у *Sypex Geo* данные хранятся в бинарнике. Нет БД по городам. Имеется библиотека на PHP.

- [Сравнение геолокационных бинарных баз и их драйверов: GeoIP, Sypex Geo, TabGeo](http://habrahabr.ru/post/227183/)
- [Дискуссия двух авторов в комментариях той же статьи](http://habrahabr.ru/post/227183/#comment_7711841)
- [Оф. сайт](http://tabgeo.com/ru/index/)

Answer (score 1):

нужна база в которой есть соответствия интервалов ip со странами

а дальше просто пишете код и сверяете айпишник посетителя с базой

Answer (score 1):

Да можно :)
Делал такую штуку для накрутки кликандеров и прочих партнерок.
Вот пример работы: http://kino-game.ru/s/ip

Архив, там всего 3 файла: http://kino-game.ru/s/ip.rar

1. ip.php (сам скрипт)
2. geoipservice.wsdl (типа библиотека, 10Кб)
3. geoipservice.asmx.xml (вроде не обязательный)

Пользуйтесь :)
если всё получится, плюсаните в репу, буду рад.

Comment: Какое отношение "смутно определить страну на уровне плюс-минус океан по IP" имеет к геопозиционированию?

Answer (score 0):

На js можно, использую кординаты полученные от браузера.